# What does "*the best approximation $A_{a}(x)$ of a function $f(x)$*" mean?

Tags: approximation-theory

I have a general question.  What does "*the best approximation $A_{a}(x)$ of a function $f(x)$*" mean? $A_{a}(x)$ stands for the approximation of $f$ at $a$ and then you get a function of $x$ which you evaluate at $x$. Does it mean that the difference between $A(a+\Delta x)$ and $f(x+\Delta x)$ for a very small $\Delta x$ is least? Or does it mean that the average error between $A_{a}(x)$ and $f(x)$ for $-\infty <x<\infty$ and $-\infty <a<\infty$ is least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more context might be helpful.  There are lots of different kinds of approximation, and usually one specifies more details that determine in what
sense this is the best approximation.  For example, it could be that
the Taylor series of $A_a(x)$ and $f(x)$ about $x=a$ agree to as many terms
as possible, or it could be that some particular norm of $A_a - f$ is minimized,
over some specified class of functions.

Comment: Or that the error is orthogonal to a certain subspace.

Comment: Okay, my question was not perfectly understandable. For example I read: "The *best* quadratic approximation of a function is: $A=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+0.5f''(a)(x-a)^2$". Then I was wondering what the "best" is referring to. I was basically wondering about the derivation of the formula and to prove it you must know, what the "best quadratic approximation" is referring to. Can you help me?

Comment: It is best in the following sense: for any other quadratic polynomial $Q(x)$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ with $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, $|A(x) - f(x)| < |Q(x) - f(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you also know the proof for this, or some source where I can look it up? Then I have another question: Could you maybe give me some advice for a book that contains information about approximations like "the best exponential or trig approximation of a function" and their proofs?

Comment: Look up "Taylor's theorem".

Answer (score 2):

First, the phrase "the best approximation" doesn't have a whole lot of meaning, in and of itself.  The "best approximation" to a function is the function itself.  No other approximation comes close!  So a more specific question is usually asked, often implicity: "What is the best polynomial approximation to this function?"  "What is the best power law approximation to this function?"  "What is the best trigonometric approximation to this function?"  etc.

Often, the function is defined -- or its values have importance -- over some finite range, and the point is to find a function of a given type (polynomial, power law, etc.) that has the best fit over that range.  This is usually *but not always* determined by "least squares" analysis, which I am sure you can look up on innumerable web sites.

Often, however, for instance when we are learning about Taylor series, the "best fit" is taken to be the polynomial that comes closest to the function over some very small $\delta x$.

Moral of the story: The definition of "best fit" is the definition used by the person speaking.  Be sure and ask lots of questions and clarify.